# Is there a way to add google adsense or admob to an ionic angular PWA?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, admob, progressive-web-apps, adsense

I am developing an ionic/angular PWA and i want to monetize the app with google adsense or admob.

After some research and tryouts I learned, that most of cordova and capacitor plugins only work for ios/android platforms. But i need to do it on platform browser in order to have it working on a PWA (please correct me if I'm wrong here).

So I'm really desperate to find a solution for that since my deadline is really tight.
So please, if anybody has something in mind i would so much appreciate that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to monetize your angular app on web platform, you should use adsense not admob because admob supports only android and iOS.

My Github page might help you to integrate adsense with Angular.
I use Ionic(Angular) for the project.

https://github.com/NP-Systems/Ionic-adsense-demo

Comment: thanks! i also found another solution, which is working for both iphone and android devices: https://np-sys.com/integrate-adsense-in-ionic-angular/